# how to convert tuples in a column rows of a pandas dataframe into repeating rows and columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tuples

I have a dataframe which contains the following data (only 3 samples are provided here):

```
data = {'Department' : ['D1', 'D2', 'D3'],
'TopWords' : [[('cat', 6), ('project', 6), ('dog', 6), ('develop', 4), ('smooth', 4), ('efficient', 4), ('administrative', 4), ('procedure', 4), ('establishment', 3), ('matter', 3)],
[('management', 21), ('satisfaction', 12), ('within', 9), ('budget', 9), ('township', 9), ('site', 9), ('periodic', 9), ('admin', 9), ('maintain', 9), ('guest', 6)],
[('manage', 2), ('ir', 2), ('mines', 2), ('implimentation', 2), ('clrg', 2), ('act', 2), ('implementations', 2), ('office', 2), ('maintenance', 2), ('administration', 2)]]}


# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Basically, each row contains a tuple of top 10 words along with their frequencies in each of Department.

I wanted to create a dataframe where (let department name get repeated and) each row contains the word from tuple in one column and frequency count in the other columns so that it should look like something this:

```
Department  Word            Counts
D1          cat             6
D1          project         6
D1          dog             6
D1          develop         4
D1          smooth          4
D1          efficient       4
D1          administrative  4
D1          procedure       4
D1          establishment   3
D1          matter          3
D2          management      21
D2          satisfaction    12
D2          within          9
D2          budget          9
D2          township        9
```

Is there any work around this type of conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to separate the list elements into different rows. Then split the tuples into different columns, e.g. using [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) + [`Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)

```
res = (
    df.explode('TopWords', ignore_index=True)
      .assign(Word=lambda df: df['TopWords'].str[0], 
              Counts=lambda df: df['TopWords'].str[1])
      .drop(columns='TopWords')
)
```

Output:

```
>>> res 

   Department             Word  Counts
0          D1              cat       6
1          D1          project       6
2          D1              dog       6
3          D1          develop       4
4          D1           smooth       4
5          D1        efficient       4
6          D1   administrative       4
7          D1        procedure       4
8          D1    establishment       3
9          D1           matter       3
10         D2       management      21
11         D2     satisfaction      12
12         D2           within       9
13         D2           budget       9
14         D2         township       9
15         D2             site       9
16         D2         periodic       9
17         D2            admin       9
18         D2         maintain       9
19         D2            guest       6
20         D3           manage       2
21         D3               ir       2
22         D3            mines       2
23         D3   implimentation       2
24         D3             clrg       2
25         D3              act       2
26         D3  implementations       2
27         D3           office       2
28         D3      maintenance       2
29         D3   administration       2
```

---

As @sammywemmy suggested, if you are dealing with a considerable amount of data, it will be faster if you wrangle it before loading it into a DataFrame.

Another way of doing it using a nested loop

```
data = {'Department' : ['D1', 'D2', 'D3'],
'TopWords' : [[('cat', 6), ('project', 6), ('dog', 6), ('develop', 4), ('smooth', 4), ('efficient', 4), ('administrative', 4), ('procedure', 4), ('establishment', 3), ('matter', 3)],
[('management', 21), ('satisfaction', 12), ('within', 9), ('budget', 9), ('township', 9), ('site', 9), ('periodic', 9), ('admin', 9), ('maintain', 9), ('guest', 6)],
[('manage', 2), ('ir', 2), ('mines', 2), ('implimentation', 2), ('clrg', 2), ('act', 2), ('implementations', 2), ('office', 2), ('maintenance', 2), ('administration', 2)]]}

records = []
for idx, top_words_list in enumerate(data['TopWords']):
    for word, count in top_words_list:
        rec = {
            'Department': data['Department'][idx],
            'Word': word,
            'Count': count
        }
        records.append(rec)
        
res = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you do the wrangling before loading into a dataframe, with  the `data` dictionary:

```py
length = [len(entry) for entry in data['TopWords']]
department = {'Department' : np.repeat(data['Department'], length)}
(pd
.DataFrame([ent for entry in data['TopWords'] for ent in entry],     
            columns = ['Word', 'Counts'])
.assign(**department)
)

               Word  Counts Department
0               cat       6         D1
1           project       6         D1
2               dog       6         D1
3           develop       4         D1
4            smooth       4         D1
5         efficient       4         D1
6    administrative       4         D1
7         procedure       4         D1
8     establishment       3         D1
9            matter       3         D1
10       management      21         D2
11     satisfaction      12         D2
12           within       9         D2
13           budget       9         D2
14         township       9         D2
15             site       9         D2
16         periodic       9         D2
17            admin       9         D2
18         maintain       9         D2
19            guest       6         D2
20           manage       2         D3
21               ir       2         D3
22            mines       2         D3
23   implimentation       2         D3
24             clrg       2         D3
25              act       2         D3
26  implementations       2         D3
27           office       2         D3
28      maintenance       2         D3
29   administration       2         D3
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @sammywemmy answer, following approach would not need `numpy` package, however due to double loops, it might not be as performant in large number of datasets.

```
d = {"Department": [], "Words": [], "Count": []}
for idx, department in enumerate(data["Department"]):
    for word, count in data["TopWords"][idx]:
        d["Department"].append(department)
        d["Words"].append(word)
        d["Count"].append(count)

print(pd.DataFrame(d))
```

@Rodalm made this code more readable using enumeration. Previously I had used simple `range()`

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback and approach @Rodalm

Comment: No worries, glad to help ;) No need to give me credit, it "pollutes" your answer, but I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

One option using a dictionary comprehension:

```
(df
 .drop(columns='TopWords')
 .join(pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['Word', 'Counts'])
                  for k,x in enumerate(df['TopWords'])}).droplevel(1))

)
```

output:

```
  Department             Word  Counts
0         D1              cat       6
0         D1          project       6
0         D1              dog       6
0         D1          develop       4
0         D1           smooth       4
0         D1        efficient       4
0         D1   administrative       4
0         D1        procedure       4
0         D1    establishment       3
0         D1           matter       3
1         D2       management      21
1         D2     satisfaction      12
1         D2           within       9
1         D2           budget       9
1         D2         township       9
1         D2             site       9
1         D2         periodic       9
1         D2            admin       9
1         D2         maintain       9
1         D2            guest       6
2         D3           manage       2
2         D3               ir       2
2         D3            mines       2
2         D3   implimentation       2
2         D3             clrg       2
2         D3              act       2
2         D3  implementations       2
2         D3           office       2
2         D3      maintenance       2
2         D3   administration       2
```